# Unable to access the value of an object to render in a div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object which houses keys ('admin', 'marketer', etc) which point to arrays of objects with keys (a user id) which point to user values (name, address, etc). I am trying to return a div which has an h2 of the outer object key with a div containing the user's name. Here is my code:

```
    let rolesAndUsers = Object.keys(this.state.roles).map((role, idx) => {
  console.log(this.state.roles);
  console.log(this.state.roles[role]);
  return (
    <div key={idx}>
      <h2>{role}</h2>
      {this.state.roles[role].map((user, idx) => {
        console.log(user);
        return <div key={idx}>{user.name}</div>
      })}
    </div>
  )
})
```

The h2 of the role name comes out, but nothing underneath each h2, and when I console.log the user name it comes back undefined, even though when I log the user object, I get {
address: "123 main st",
email:"test@gmail.com",
name: "john smith"}

```
    return (
  <div className="App">
    {rolesAndUsers}
    <button className="update-button cf-btn-primary"onClick={this.handleClickUpdate}>Update</button>
  </div>
);
```

this.state.roles:

```
{Admin: Array(1), Marketer: Array(1), Developer: Array(2)}
Admin
:
Array(1)
0
:
{4AwbLJ123HPuEonrU: {…}}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
Developer
:
Array(2)
0
:
{7CU7sLAxbhdNF2jkq5Nk: {…}}
1
:
{4xYz3qegVajoeTpOrma: {…}}
```

Any insight as to why I can't get the name of a user into the div inside of an admin name? Thanks

Comment: show your this.state.roles please

Comment: any chance `user` is the string `{ address: "123 main st", email:"test@gmail.com", name: "john smith"}` and not the object `{ address: "123 main st", email:"test@gmail.com", name: "john smith"}`?

Comment: when i put Object.keys(user) inside the div rather than the user's name, it properly renders the id of the user in the div, but I can't access anything inside